# Trigger the mouseover event of a tag that does not seem to be on top?

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML code that looks something like

```
<div>
    <a>
        <img />
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to handle a `mouseover` event on the `img` tag.

But placing the mouse over the image triggers a `mouseover` event on the `div` tag instead of the `img` tag.

What can I do to trigger a `mouseover` event for the `img` tag without changing the HTML structure?

I have tried changing the `z-index`, but that did not work.

Comment: *"But placing the mouse over the image triggers a mouseover event on the div tag instead of the img tag."* No, it triggers `mouseover` on the `img` (that event then bubbles to the `a` and to the `div`, after `img`). What makes you think it's not trigger on the `img`?

Comment: My event handler does not trigger. Maybe it is only my jQuery selector that is incorrect then and I was barking up the wrong tree. I will look at it again tomorrow when at work.

Comment: a minimal snippet reproducing your problem ( including `js` ) can be helpful

Comment: @user1283776 - Your best bet is to delete the question. You can post a new one from work if you can't figure it out (but you probably will figure it out). If you don't, when posting the new question, please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). Happy coding!

Comment: Its already answered so I cant delete it. Thanks for the good suggestion regardless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in this example how the `mouseOver` event bubbles up the tags hierarchy, just like **@T.J. Crowder** commented (check the blue "image"). 
This only happens when all the tags (`div` and `a` as well) are assigned with handlers.

However, if you want to assign an event handler via JavaScript, it still works as expected (check the red "image").

```js
document.getElementById("img").onmouseover = function() {console.log("mouse over red IMG")};
```

```css
img {
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}

#img {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
Triggered by HTML attribute "onmouseover":
<div onmouseover="console.log('mouse over DIV')">
  <a onmouseover="console.log('mouse over A')">
    <img src="picture.jpg" onmouseover="console.log('mouse over blue IMG')">
  </a>
</div>

<br>

Triggered by JavaScript:
<div>
  <a>
    <img src="picture.jpg" id="img">
  </a>
</div>
```